# Collapse Multiple Records Into a Single Record With Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, db2

In a program I'm maintaining we were given a massive (~500 lines) SQL statement by the customer. It is used for generating flat files with fixed length records for transmitting data to another big business. Since its a massive flat file its not relational and the standard normal forms of data are collapsed. So, if you have a record that can have multiple codes associated, in this case upto 19, they all have be written into single line, but seperate fields, in the flat file.

*Note: this example is simplified.*

The data might look like this, with three tables:

```
RECORDS
record_id   firstname   lastname    
--------------------------------    
123         Bob         Schmidt
324         George      Washington
325         Ronald      Reagan
290         George      Clooney


CODE_TABLE
code_id     code_cd     code_txt
--------------------------------
5           3           President
2           4           Actor    
3           7           Plumber


CODES_FOR_RECORDS
record_id   code_cd
-------------------
123         7    
325         3
290         4
324         3
325         4
123         4
```

This needs to produce records like:

```
firstname   lastname    code1       code2       code3
Bob         Schmidt     Actor       Plumber     NULL
George      Washington  President   NULL        NULL
Ronald      Reagon      Actor       President   NULL
George      Clooney     Actor       NULL        NULL
```

The portion of the current query we were given looks like this, but with 19 code columns instead of the 5:

```
select 
    x.record_id,
    max(case when  x.rankk = 1  then code_txt end) as CodeColumn1,
    max(case when  x.rankk = 2  then code_txt end) as CodeColumn2,
    max(case when  x.rankk = 3  then code_txt end) as CodeColumn3,
    max(case when  x.rankk = 4  then code_txt end) as CodeColumn4,
    max(case when  x.rankk = 5  then code_txt end) as CodeColumn5,
from 
    (
        select 
            r.record_id,
            ct.code_txt as ctag ,
            dense_rank() over (partition by r.record_id order by cfr.code_id) as rankk
        from            
            records as r
            codes_for_records as cfr,
            code_table as ct
        where
            r.record_id = cfr.record_id
            and ct.code_cd = cfr.code_cd
            and cfr.code_cd is not null
            and ct.code_txt not like '%V%'
    ) as x
where
    x.record_id is not null
group by
    x.record_id
```

I trimmed down things for simplicties sake, but the actual statment includes an inner query and a join and more where conditions, but that should get the idea across. My brain is telling me there has to be a better way, but I'm not an SQL expert. We are using DB2 v8 if that helps. And the codes have to be in seperate columns, so no coalescing things into a single string. Is there a cleaner solution than this?

**Update:**

I ended up just refacorting the original query, it sill uses the ugly MAX() business, but overall the query is much more readable due to reworking other parts.

Comment: When I write code to transform data manually, the procedure is rarely under 1000 lines long. That code looks pretty simple and straightforward to me.

Comment: Maybe its that I'm not really familiar with SQL, because to me that seems kind of convoluted. And part of it is a 1,000 lines when seperated into logical chunks isn't to bad. 500 lines of SQL that is so interconnected it seems like spaghetti is another thing, IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you are looking for is [pivoting](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/pivoting_tables56?lang=en_us).

```
WITH joined_table(firstname, lastname, code_txt, rankk) AS
(
SELECT
  r.firstname,
  r.lastname,
  ct.code_txt,
  dense_rank() over (partition by r.record_id order by cfr.code_id) as rankk
FROM
  records r
INNER JOIN
  codes_for_records cfr
  ON r.record_id = cfr.record_id
INNER JOIN
  codes_table ct
  ON ct.code_cd = cfr.code_cd
),

decoded_table(firstname, lastname,
  CodeColumn1, CodeColumn2, CodeColumn3, CodeColumn4, CodeColumn5) AS
(
  SELECT
    firstname,
    lastname,
    DECODE(rankk, 1, code_txt),
    DECODE(rankk, 2, code_txt),
    DECODE(rankk, 3, code_txt),
    DECODE(rankk, 4, code_txt),
    DECODE(rankk, 5, code_txt)
  FROM
    joined_table jt
)

SELECT
  firstname,
  lastname,
  MAX(CodeColumn1),
  MAX(CodeColumn2),
  MAX(CodeColumn3),
  MAX(CodeColumn4),
  MAX(CodeColumn5)
FROM
  decoded_table dt
GROUP BY
  firstname,
  lastname;
```

Note that I've never actually done this myself before. I'm relying on the [linked document](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/pivoting_tables56?lang=en_us) as a reference.

You might need to include the record_id to account for duplicate names.

Edit: Added the GROUP BY.

Comment: Interesting. I'll give this a shot.

Comment: I still think all this `MAX()` business is ugly.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions is using of recursive query:

```
with recursive_view (record_id, rankk, final) as
(
  select
    record_id, 
    rankk,
    cast (ctag as varchar (100))
  from inner_query t1

  union all 

  select
    t1.record_id,
    t1.rankk,
    /* all formatting here */
    cast (t2.final || ',' || t1.ctag as varchar (100))
  from 
    inner_query t1,
    recursive_view t2
  where 
    t2.rankk < t1.rankk
    and t1.record_id = t2.record_id
    and locate(t1.ctag, t2.final) = 0
)
select record_id, final from recursive_view;
```

Can't guarantee that it works, but hope it will be helpful. Another way is using of custom aggregate function.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. However each code needs to be left as its on collumn. It can't be joined into one giant string.

Comment: It can be formatted by padding to looks like bunch of columns. Otherwise without pivot and dynamic sql you are forced to use duplicate max(case) constructions.